# Vector Basis (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I just started learning about vector basis and was wondering if a basis is a subset that spans a subspace and is linearly independent, does that mean a basis must form a square matrix?

Comment: A basis for a vector space is a subset of that vector space that has to satisfy two conditions: 1) all vectors in the set must be linearly independent, and 2) the vectors must linearly span all the vector space. About your square matrix question, you need the definition of coordinate vectors for your question to make sense, otherwise how do you put the set $\{1,x,x^{2}\}$ in a matrix which is a basis for $P_{2}(\mathbf{R})$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "form a square matrix"? Can you write a basis for, I don't know, $\mathbb R^2$, and use it to "form a square matrix"?

Comment: Hi, I mean for example for a basis of R^3, there must be 3 vectors in the basis and each of the vectors are in R^3 as well. Hence, if we write them as column vectors next to each other, the basis would be something of a 3x3 matrix? So my question is is this always true?

Sorry if it sounds weird or dumb, I am still new to the concepts

Comment: Yes, it's always true, but it's a trivial observation. Any element of $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and since dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$, any basis consists of $n$ vectors. In total, $n\times n$ numbers. However, if you switch to some abstract $n$-dimensional space $V$ and have basis $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ there is no canonical way to assign vector-columns to $b_i$'s. Such an assignment is essentially picking a new basis for your space $V$, writing each $b_i$ as a linear combination in new basis, and then you can put all coefficients into a square matrix. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can talk about making matrices, you need a coordinate system, which is to say you need a basis. A basis is an ordered set of vectors $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ with certain properties. A priori you can't express a basis vector using any kind of coordinates, because the basis is needed to *make* the coordinates.

Once you have a basis, you can express every vector in your space as a linear combination of the basis vectors. For instance, some vector $v$ can be written as
$$
v=v_1b_1+\cdots+v_nb_n
$$
where the $v_i$ are scalars. In linear algebra we also write this as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the basis vectors $b_i$ are elided. But just because we don't write the basis vectors that doesn't mean they aren't there.

And from there the rest of linear algebra flows. Including matrices. Given a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, and a chosen basis on each of $V$ and $W$, you can use those bases to express $T$ as a table of numbers in a certain manner (the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors of $V$, expanded in the basis of $W$), and this table is called a matrix.

This is the order things happen in. First you have a linear transformation and two bases. From there you make a matrix. At least for me, realizing that coordinate systems and matrices come second to vectors and linear transformations is what made linear algebra really click.

It is interesting to see what happens when $V=W$ and $T$ is the identity map (which sends each vector to itself), but we still have two different bases. Then the matrix representation of $T$  is called a *change of basis matrix*. The columns of $T$ will then be the expansion of the basis vectors of $V$ using the basis vectors of $W$ (this way of thinking about things is the only way I've been able to remember which way that goes). It will be a square matrix. This is likely the matrix you mention in your question.

It is common to do this and not explicitly mention that $V$ has a basis. Or they might say that $V$ has the so-called "standard basis". (Which in this interpretation doesn't make much sense; any basis is its own standard basis. There are vector spaces with bases that stand out as more standard than others, in particular those where the elements already look like coordinates, but this is not true for all vector spaces).

If $V$ is a proper subspace of $W$, and $T$ is the inclusion map, then once again the columns of the matrix representation of $T$ will correspond to the expansion of the basis vectors of $V$ using the basis vectors of $W$. It will not be a square matrix.

However, if you are using the basis of $W$ to express the vectors of $V$, which is quite common, then you don't have a basis for $V$ and all of the above goes out the window. You will in that case have to think about $T$ as the identity map $W\to W$, only we happen to only use it on vectors from $V$. As we use the same basis twice here, the matrix representation of $T$ is the identity matrix. It is still square.

A basis on its own does not yield a matrix. To make a matrix you need two spaces (which might be the same space), a basis on each (which again might be the same), and a linear transformation between them.

Comment: a question: an $n$ by $m$ matrix with entries in a field $F$ is just a function $f : \{1,\dots,n\}\times\{1,\dots,m\}\to F$. i see no mention of a coordinate system to construct a matrix.

Comment: @CSquared Well, that's what I mean by "a table of numbers". Indeed, you don't need a coordinate system to fill a table full of numbers. You do need a coordinate system (or two, actually) in order to make sense of such a table of numbers as a linear transformation between two vector spaces in the context of linear algebra.